# Why is my vpc peering connection not working in aws?

Tags: amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have an mlflow tracking server deployed in one vpc and a task in ecs deployed in another vpc. The 2 vpc's are in the same region. The mlflow server is deployed with an internal load balancer. I tried to set up a peering connection via the aws console in order to call the mlflow server from the ecs task in the other vpc.

The mlflow vpc has 3 routing tables, one for each subnet. I added a route in each of these tables with the "local" cdir block of the ecs task's vpc as the destination, and the peering connection as the target. I then added a route in the ecs task's vpc's routing table with the "local" cdir block of the mlflow vpc as the destination and the peering connection as the target (as per the example here: https://dev.to/aws-builders/creating-a-vpc-peering-connection-8j).

I have made sure that the mlflow vpc's access control list allows inbound and outbound traffic from the other vpc, and that the other vpc's acl allows traffic from the mlflow vpc, and that the load balancer's security group allows traffic from the other vpc's cdir block.

I'm trying to call the url of the internal load balancer, but I keep running into a connection refused error:

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Any help would be much appreciated.